# In bash, how do I count the number of lines in a variable?

Tags: bash, string

I have a variable which has a string stored in it and need to check if it has lines in it:

```
var=`ls "$sdir" | grep "$input"`
```

pseudo-code:

```
while [ ! $var's number of lines -eq 1 ]
  do something
```

That's my idea on how to check it. `echo $var | wc -l` doesn't work - it always says `1`, even though it has `3`.

`echo -e` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Quotes matter.

```
echo "$var" | wc -l
```

Comment: thank you so much, i'm such a fool...               Also, if I already have double quotes surrounding the command, how do use that inside?  i.e. "echo "$var" | wc -l"

Comment: Why would you have double quotes surrounding the command? It's not a command if it's surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: its because I use: echo "$(ls /dir/ | grep "$string")"            ...but this is just an example, theres a way i just dont know it

Comment: That's not quotes surrounding the command, that's quotes surrounding the command substitution. The pairs of quotes will not interfere.

Comment: This has a subtlety. An empty string will return 1 since echo on an empty string prints a newline.

Comment: In other words: `if [ -z "$var" ]; then printf '%s\n' '0'; else printf '%s\n' "${var%$'\n'}" | wc -l; fi`. Try with `var=` (no lines), `var='foo'` and `var=$'foo\n'` (both one line in the *nix sense).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That's false. try typing in `"whoami"` (quotes included) for example. Its effect is no different from quoting anywhere else. (that is, the meaning of `"ls"` and `ls` are identical to the shell)

Comment: And yet another way to get it into a variable:

`LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "${var}")`

Comment: Can do `echo -n` to make it not add a newline and return 0 for an empty string (as you'd expect)

Comment: @Tim `echo -n` will simply decrease the count by one.
@lucifurious `echo $(wc -l <<< "${NONEXISTENTVAR}")` still gives 1, not 0

Answer (score 132):

The accepted answer and other answers posted here do not work in case of an empty variable (undefined or empty string).

This works:

```
echo -n "$VARIABLE" | grep -c '^'
```

For example:

```
ZERO=
ONE="just one line"
TWO="first
> second"

echo -n "$ZERO" | grep -c '^'
0
echo -n "$ONE" | grep -c '^'
1
echo -n "$TWO" | grep -c '^'
2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce what sounds like a bug from @PolyTekPatrick, i.e. `WHITESPACE_ONE='   '` in my shell (bash) still works, correctly reporting one line.

Comment: You're right. I swore I tested it, but I must have missed the double quotes or mistyped something. One or more whitespace chars does indeed get counted as 1 line as should be expected. I deleted my earlier comment to avoid confusing people.

Comment: Perfect! This should be the accepted answer. It is the only solution so far that properly answers the question for all cases. Thanks for showing the test cases to prove it.

Comment: YES! I too think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is correct, but can be simplified using `printf` rather than `echo -n`. I've added this as an alternate answer, in order to include test results. See below.

Comment: I don't see how `printf` is any "simpler". It's test code anyway, what matters is the `grep` part.

Comment: It says `Suggested edit queue is full`. Please, review the queue of the answer. We want to append, too!

Comment: Have a look at [my pure bash version (method 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957175/9243840). It doesn't rely on external commands and works for all cases.

Answer (score 35):

Another way using *here strings* in bash:

```
wc -l <<< "$var"
```

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314679/in-bash-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-variable/17062359?noredirect=1#comment75987107_17062359), an empty `$var` will result in 1 line instead of 0 lines because *here strings* add a newline character in this case ([explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char)).

Comment: I had to do this to get the correct answer:
`wc -l <<<"$(echo "$var")"`
(yes, every single symbol was necessary)

Comment: @NicolaiS Then you did something wrong. What was the content of `$var`?

Comment: `var="a\nb\nc"` Gives 1 from `wc -l`

Comment: @NicolaiS That is correct because your `var` contains _one line_: You didn't interpret the `\n` with anything. Put multiple lines into your `var` and it will work, e.g. with `var="foo<ENTER>bar<ENTER>baz"<ENTER>`.

Comment: Doesn't work: `wc -l <<< $undefined_var` return 1. Should be returned 0. Have tested `wc` and found, that it return 1 for empty or undefined variable in all cases: `wc -l` (byte counts), `wc -m` option (character counts), `wc -l`. Everywhere it returns 1, instead 0. For working solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399738/2913477)

Comment: `xxd <<< ''` create this hexdump `00000000: 0a`. Therefore, `<<<` (Here Strings) add newline character to any contents.

Comment: @MiniMax Thanks, I added your input to my answer. You can find an explanation for this behaviour [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char).

Comment: Note, In default ubuntu shell (DASH) >>> is not allowed.

Comment: @ilansch The question is tagged with `bash` so that's not a reason to downvote.

Comment: i did not downvote anything, just commented to note dash in ubuntu is default and not bash. take it easy man

Comment: @ilansch My fault then, sorry. I assumed you downvoted because I got one yesterday after your comment.

Answer (score 14):

No one has mentioned parameter expansion, so here are a couple of ways using pure bash.

**Method 1**

Remove non-newline characters, then get string length + 1. *Quotes are important*.

```
 var="${var//[!$'\n']/}"
 echo $((${#var} + 1))
```

**Method 2**

Convert to array, then get array length. *For this to work, don't use quotes*.

```
 set -f # disable glob (wildcard) expansion
 IFS=$'\n' # let's make sure we split on newline chars
 var=(${var})
 echo ${#var[@]}
```

Comment: Method 2 is cleaner and probably faster. Howver it relies on the `IFS`. So set `IFS=$'\n'` to make sure the variable is split at new lines when expanding it into an array: `IFS=$'\n'; var=(${var})`

Comment: I like Method 2 because of its minimum overhead: no external commands and not even a builtin is in sight. It's also quite readable.

Comment: ShellCheck complains though: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206. It's onto something. `set -f` is needed to avoid unwanted glob expansion. Try to use Method 2 on `var=$'*\n.*'`.

Comment: auto-bonus for pure internal bash w/o external `wc -l`

Answer (score 13):

A simpler version of @Julian's answer, that works for all strings, with or without trailing \n (it does count a file containing just a single trailing \n as empty):

`printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"`

- Returns zero: unset variable, empty string, string containing bare newline
- Returns 1: any non-empty line, with or without trailing newline
- etc

Output:

```
# a=
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
0

# a=""
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
0

# a="$(printf "")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
0

# a="$(printf "\n")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
0

# a="$(printf " \n")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
1

# a="$(printf " ")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
1

# a="aaa"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
1

# a="$(printf "%s" "aaa")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
1

# a="$(printf "%s\n" "aaa")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
1

# a="$(printf "%s\n%s" "aaa" "bbb")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
2

# a="$(printf "%s\n%s\n" "aaa" "bbb")"
# printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
2
```

Comment: +1. Passing flags to `echo` (such as `echo -n`) is not standard, and may give different results on different implementations. Whereas `printf` does what we want by default. As a bonus, using `printf` saves you a process, since it's a shell built-in. (Suggestion: `printf "$a" | wc -l` is more concise and avoids unnecessary use of `grep`)

Comment: @joshtch Well.. no. As said by others in this discussion `printf .... | wc -l` will only remove one extra line (the newline) so that in case of an **empty line** the result will be **0**. Correct. But if we pass 2 lines, the result will be 1, where the same variable passed to the `printf ... | grep "^"` will correctly return 2. Besides, using directly `printf "$a"` is very dangerous, because it can lead to silent errors if the string accidentally contains characters like `%s`, `%d` and so on... Same if the string starts with a dash. Instead, the 2 parameter in `printf` is automatically escaped

Comment: This is not quite correct. The line `a="$(printf "\n")"` sets `a` to an empty string, not to a bare newline. To run the newline test in bash, try `a=$'\n'; printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"`. The count will be 1. If you want to omit **ALL** blank lines from the count, change the grep test from `"^"` to `"."`. Finally, as for `printf` vs. `echo -n`, it is technically true that `printf` is more portable. But in most situations `echo -n` is going to be just fine. Either command results in the same count for every test case.

Answer (score 9):

You can substitute the "wc -l" with "wc -w" to rather count the number of words instead of lines. This will not count any new lines and can be used to test if your original results are empty before you continue.

Comment: `wc -l` solutions outputs 1 even if the input variable is empty, so `wc -w` will be better to use.

Answer (score 5):

Another method to count number of lines in a variable - assuming you did check it was successfully filled or it is not empty, for that just check $? after *var* subshell result affectation - :

```
readarray -t tab <<<"${var}"
echo ${#tab[@]}
```

*readarray|mapfile* is bash internal command which converts input file, or *here string* in this case, to array based on newlines.

*-t* flag prevents storing newlines at end of array's cells, useful for later use of stored values

Advantages of this method are :

- no external command (wc, grep, ...)
- no subshell (pipe)
- no IFS issues (restore after modification, tricky to use with command-limited scope on internal commands, ...)

Comment: Which is typically more expensive, an extra process of a temporary file (due to here string)?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid filename in `wc -l` command:

```
lines=$(< "$filename" wc -l)
echo "$lines"
```

Answer (score 3):

The top voted answers fail if no results were returned by a grep.

```
Homer Simpson
Marge Simpson
Bart Simpson
Lisa Simpson
Ned Flanders
Rod Flanders
Todd Flanders
Moe Szyslak
```

This is [the **wrong** way to do it](https://uproxx.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/ralph-simpsons-wiggum.jpg):

```
wiggums=$(grep -iF "Wiggum" characters.txt);
num_wiggums=$(echo "$wiggums" | wc -l);
echo "There are ${num_wiggums} here!";
```

There will tell us, there is `1` *Wiggum* in the list, even if there aren't any.

Instead, you need to do one extra check to see if the variable is empty (`-z`, as in "is zero"). If grep didn't return anything, the variable will be empty.

```
matches=$(grep -iF "VanHouten" characters.txt);

if [ -z "$matches" ]; then
    num_matches=0;
else
    num_matches=$(echo "$matches" | wc -l);
fi

echo "There are ${num_matches} VanHoutens on the list";
```