# bash - cleaner way to count the number of lines in a variable using pure bash?

Tags: bash

I have a variable containing some command output, and I want to count the number of lines in that output. I am trying to do this using pure bash (instead of piping to wc like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314679/in-bash-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-variable)).

The best I have come up with seems kind of cumbersome:

```
function count_lines() {
    num_lines=0
    while IFS='' read -r line; do
        ((num_lines++))
    done <<< "$1"
    echo "$num_lines"
}

count_lines "$my_var"
```

Is there a cleaner or shorter way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `wc`? But if you absolutely want to avoid it, your function seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count_lines () (
  IFS=$'\n'
  set -f
  set -- $1
  echo $#
)
```

Some tricks used:

1. The function is defined using a subshell instead of a command group to localize the change to `IFS` and the `-f` shell option. (You could be less fancy and use `local IFS=$'\n'` instead, and running `set +f` at the end of the function).
2. Disable filename generation to avoid any metacharacters in the argument from expanding and interfering with the line count.
3. Once `IFS` is changed, set the positional parameters for the function using *unquoted* parameter expansion for the argument.
4. Finally, output the number of positional parameters; there is one per line in the original argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
x=( $variable )
```

Now ${#x[@]} will contain the number of 'lines'.  (Use "set +f" to undo "set -f".)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution I came up with:

`export x=0;while read i;do export x=$(($x+1));done < /path/to/your/file;echo $x`

Comment: in `awk` (GNU tool, not `bash` internal): `awk 'END{print NR}' < /path/to/your/file`