# Pre-commit hook with echo -n behaving differently when run by git compared to when run manually

Tags: git, bash, pre-commit-hook

I've written a pre-commit hook to check that I've not accidentally used tabs to indent my new code.

I developed it by staging various changes and running the hook manually by typing `$ bash .git/hooks/pre-commit` to simulate the hook being triggered by git (I thought this was a pretty accurate environment). However when it is actually run by git during a commit it is behaving differently. Why is this?

Here's a simplified example of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Default to zero which means the changes are good and the commit can go ahead
exitstatus=0

# Grab the lines with the plus symbol and tab characters at the start (eg. New lines, indented wrongly)
tabbedlines=$( git diff --cached -U0 code/ | egrep "^\+\t" )

# Count the lines (** THIS IS THE BIT THAT BEHAVES DIFFERENTLY **)
tabbedlinecount=$( echo -n "$tabbedlines" | grep -c '^' )

if [ $tabbedlinecount -gt 0 ]
then
  exitstatus=1
fi

exit $exitstatus
```

Essentially it's that line that starts with `tabbedlinecount=...` that is behaving differently. `echo` with the `-n` flag returns 0 when run in the bash environment but 1 when run by git during a commit. I have proven this by changing it to use `printf` instead which behaves consistently and thus fixes the problem, but even though I've fixed it I still want to understand why?!

Is this something to do with the shell that git uses compared to the shell my terminal uses? I'm a bit out of my depth now. Help me stack overflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Can you also show us the actual input here to try out?

Comment: Are you using `GNU grep`? Can yo show us the `grep --version`?

Comment: grep --version returns `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: `echo -n` is not portable; use `printf '%s' "$tabbedlines"` should the need arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script uses `#!/bin/sh`. If that shell is `dash` (or another *strictly* conforming POSIX shell, then the output of `echo -n whatever` is

```
$ echo -n
-n
```

that is, `-n` is not recognized as an option to suppress a trailing newline. Use `printf` instead.

```
$ tabbedlinecount=$( printf '%s' "$tabbedlines" | grep -c '^' )
```

Comment: I'd never even heard of Dash! Thanks for the knowledge friend.

Comment: Also, to count lines, `grep -c ^` is a bit silly: just pipe to `wc -l`. However, we don't need to *count* lines; egrep's output status tells us the answer right away (0 if any matches are found, 1 if not). Hence: `if git diff --cached -U0 code/ | egrep "^\+\t" >/dev/null; then ...` I don't think `\t` works in FreeBSD egrep though.

Comment: @torek piping the output to `wc -l` will return 1 in the case when zero matches exist. I went with `grep -c ^` after reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314679/in-bash-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-variable/6314682#42399738

Comment: @MartinJoiner: No; try it: `git diff -U0 | egrep '^\+B' | wc -l` produces `3` in a repo where I have 3 added lines that start with `B`, and produces `0` in the same repo when grepping for `X`. So `count=$(git diff -U0 | egrep '^\+B' | wc -l)` does the trick, for instance. (It's important *not* to capture the text in a shell variable first so that you don't have `echo "$var"` producing a newline.) Note that there is leading white space in `$count` so it must be tested with space-stripping. But again, unless you *need* the actual line count, the egrep exit status alone suffices.