# How do I count the number of lines in a bash variable, respecting emptiness?

Tags: string, bash, is-empty, line-count

We know [how to count the number of lines in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314679/in-bash-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-variable). However, as noted in comments and answers there, the semantics are quirky when it comes to empty variables, as an empty variable is usually counted the same as a non-empty, no-newline variable:

```
$ echo -n "" | wc -l
0
$ echo -n "foo" | wc -l
0
$ echo "" | wc -l
1
$ echo "foo" | wc -l
1
```

not so good, if you want to count the number of results some other command returned.

Now, a partial workaround is suggested in one of the answers to that question:

```
printf "%s" "$a" | grep -c "^"
```

but that's not exactly what I'm after either, since it counts a non-empty variable whose value is a newline as having 0 lines.

My question: Other than counting "regularly" and then explicitly checking for the case of emptiness, is there a decent way to obtain such a count in bash?

Comment: "It counts a non-empty variable holding a newline as having 0 lines" – does it? This `printf "%s" $'x\n' | grep -c "^"` returns `1` for me.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I meant holding just a newline with nothing else.

Comment: Do you want to count empty lines after the first one? What should be the result of `printf "a\n\n\n\nb\n" | countcommand` and data not ending with a newline: `printf "a\nb"` or `printf "a\n"` ?

Comment: @WalterA: Pretend that it's some shell utility the produces that output. Those typically finish things off with a newline for the prompt to be on line start. So, `a\n\n\n\nb\n` should give 5, I think; the last empty line, without the `\n`, will not be counted. `a\nb` - two lines but it's input I'm less likely to get. `a\n` - one line. Also, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
$ echo -n "foo" | awk 'END {print NR}'
1
$ echo -n "" | awk 'END {print NR}'
0
```

Comment: Looks like the most robust solution, even if awk is a bit of a large hammer.

Answer (score 0):

The following will count the number of newlines:

```sh
printf %s "$var" | tr -d -c '\n' | wc -c
```

It will work in all instances except when the last line is missing a newline.

---

You can test separately if a variable is empty like this:

```sh
test -z "$var" && echo "var is empty"

test -n "$var" && echo "var is not empty"
```